# Which philosophers were the strongest supporters of individual privacy?

Tags: political-philosophy

Philosophers differ on their opinions of privacy.  Who were the strongest supporters of individual privacy?

Answer (score 1):

1. The Monist: An International Journal of General Philosophical Enquiry: January, 2008: Volume 91, Number 1: Privacy
   Smith, Barry; Thalos, Mariam (editors)
   Published by State University of New York Press, New York, 2008.
2. Clayton, Richard & Tomlinson, Hugh, Privacy and Freedom of Expression, ISBN 10: 0199246386 / ISBN 13: 9780199246380
   Published by OUP Oxford, 2001.
3. Stefano Scoglio, Transforming Privacy: A Transpersonal Philosophy of Rights (Praeger Series in Transformational Politics and Political Science). ISBN 10: 0275956075 / ISBN 13: 9780275956073.
   Published by Praeger Publishers, 1998
4. INNESS, JULIE, PRIVACY, INTIMACY, AND ISOLATION, Published by Oxford University Press, 1996.
5. Privacy: Nomos XIII. ed.J. Roland Pennock , John W. Chapman, NY : Atherton Press, 1971.
6. Fried, Charles, An Anatomy of Values (Cambridge: Harvard University Press, 1970), Ch. IX.
7. Hofstadter, J. H. and Horowitz, G., The Right to Privacy, (New York: Central Book Co., 1964).

**John Stuart Mill**'s On Liberty (1859) with its rule against interference in the lives of others except where demonstrable harm to needs be avoided, is relevant in the background.